# How to specify a manager leader in a docker swarm constraint

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am aware I can manually a constraint to a leader node. But, there may already be a built-in way to specify a leader node in a swarm.

Basically, I need to prevent containers from running on the leader node. They can run anywhere else except the leader. Is there a built in way to specify a leader node in the constraint?

Comment: Why do you need this specifically? Can you talk about your use case? What if the leader goes down and another manager takes over, all containers should be evicted? What's special about the leader (and not a general manager) in your case?

Comment: @johnharris85 Our leader is the ci/cd server. I didn't want the ci/cd server running docker containers

Comment: How do you control the leader to be the ci/cd server? How many managers do you have?

Comment: @BMitch We will have two managers. We manually designated the cicd server to be the leader. The reason is because we have docker awarm commands in the jenkins build. So, when jenkins deploys a container it will never be deployed on the jenkins server.

Comment: You do not want 2 managers, that's fault intolerant. If you lose either, your swarm is down. You'll improve your HA by demoting one to a worker. Swarm can dynamically adjust the leader, so if you're manually scheduling CI on the current leader, you may as well bind it to a label and bind your other services to run on different labels.

Comment: Coupling things tightly to specific machines seems like an anti-pattern. Why not have a tiny bootstrap around Jenkins startup that runs a drain (see @BMitch answer below) on whatever `hostname` is. Then even if the node goes down and Jenkins balances to somewhere else you're covered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent containers from running on a node, you can do this for all containers using:

```
docker node update --availability drain $your_node_name
```

To do this for a single service, you can add a constraint on the node type:

```
docker service create --constraint 'node.role==worker' --name $your_service $image_name
```

I don't think there's any way to do this on only the leader with a group of managers, it's all or none. You may be able to script something external that checks the current leader and updates node labels.